# How to align ImageView & TextView align right in a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like show my Page view header like below,

[image]

I'm using the following layout using, but the image and second textview not moving to right, its all align center.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/transbg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="6"   
                android:gravity="center"    
                >
               <TextView
               android:id="@+id/txtName"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"                               
               android:text="Magasin"
               android:textColor="#FFF"               
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:textStyle="bold" />

               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                   android:layout_weight="0"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">

                   <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:gravity="right"
                       android:src="@drawable/yellow2" />

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvCredits"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:gravity="right"
                       android:text="test"
                       android:textColor="#fff"
                       android:textSize="16sp" />
               </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>                   
    </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

how I can align one image view and textview right aligned.

Comment: Which one do you want to align ? id ?

Comment: @+id/imageView1 and @+id/tvCredits

Comment: why don't you check `android:gravity="center"` in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this one and let me know if it is what you want.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Magasin"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvCredits" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCredits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT :**  If you want to make the same layout with easier and more efficient way, you can use this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/black" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Magasin"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvCredits"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCredits"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @user1281750 I just modified the code of "Able Alias". He might have a purpose of using it, so I didn't change.

Comment: But I wouldn't use it that way. It can be done way easier than this.

Comment: @osayilgan Thanks. but one issue, the textview android:id="@+id/txtName" aligh left, but I need that align center, how to do?

Comment: @AbleAlias Replace `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true", android:layout_centerVertical="true"` with `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Comment: only for "@+id/txtName"

Comment: Wow... its working perfect ... accepting the answer now... a last question, is it possible to add a padding on right side, need to put some space on right side.

Comment: Of course, give padding to the parent of textView (Relative Layout).`android:paddingRight="10dp"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Magasin"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCredits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="right">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:background="@drawable/transbg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="6"   
            android:gravity="center"    
            >
           <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txtName"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"                               
           android:text="Magasin"
           android:textColor="#FFF"               
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_weight="0"
               android:gravity="right|center"
               android:orientation="horizontal">

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="right"
                   android:src="@drawable/yellow2" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tvCredits"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="right"
                   android:text="test"
                   android:textColor="#fff"
                   android:textSize="16sp" />
           </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>                   
       </LinearLayout>   
      </LinearLayout> 

      </LinearLayout>
```